# Programmatically switching MVC view controllers - iOS

Tags: model-view-controller, ios, uiviewcontroller, view

How do I programmatically switch the view controller in iOS?

So example - I have a menu MVC setup, now I click "Help" How do I programmatically hand this off to the help view controller to load that MVC setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this a View-based or Navigation-based application?

For a Navigation-based application, your AppDelegate should provide you access to a shared UINavigationController which you can use to push/pop UIViewControllers

```
[self.navController pushViewController:helpViewController animated:YES]
```

then when the user wants to leave the Help view and go back to the main screen, you would pop it off.  This functionality is provided automatically by the left/back button in the UINavigationBar, but you can trigger it manually using the popViewcontrollerAnimated selector:

```
[self.navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

For View-based applications, you move between screens by manipulating the subviews

```
[window addSubview:helpViewController.view]
```

Comment: While the nav-based comments are worthwhile, you open yourself to a world of problems by using the approach: `[window addSubview:helpViewController.view]`.  I won't belabour this--it's all been covered [here](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/).

Answer (score 1):

Using Utility Template should be the fastest solution.
You will have two views that can switch back and forth magically.

However, Those can be implemented by the following steps

on help button touched , just call

```
[self presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated];
```

there should be back button on the HelpViewController

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated]; //call to return back to parent view controller
```

have a fun ^^

Comment: What if you want to navigate between more than two views?  I have an app that has many views but isn't linear, so I don't think a nav-view app is appropriate.  any suggestions?

Comment: Tab bar application is the most appropriate way to do what you want (with minimum effort).